# Google Speech API fails for file size >1 mb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Cloud Speech API in my node.js application. This hosted in Google Compute Engine. I use Google Storage as input source for Speech To Text. Whenever I use audio files of <1 mb everything works fine. But it starts to fail without any proper error message for files larger than that. Below is the code I use and the error I get

```
speechClient.startRecognition('gs://bucket-name/filename.flac', {
    encoding: 'FLAC',
    sampleRate: 16000
}, function(err, operation, apiResponse){
    if(err){
        console.log('FIRST FAILURE');
        console.log({
            error: err,
            response: apiResponse
        });
        callback({
            error: err,
            response: apiResponse
        }, null);
    }
    else{
        operation
        .on('error', function(err) {
            callback({
               error: err
            }, null);
        })
        .on('complete', function(transcript) {
            callback(null, transcript);
        });
    }
})
```

Error

```
FIRST FAILURE
{"error":{"code":400,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}}},"response":null}
```

Also noticed that for a 45 second clip that worked it just gave me transcript of just a few (around 15) seconds.